# If else condition and logical operators

Tags: java, android, if-statement, logical-operators

This is my code for searching a 2 places that call the method of the `polyline`. When my `editext` **Tabaco - Malinao** it's calling the method properly same as **Tabaco-Bacacay, Tabaco-Santo Domingo, Tabaco-Malilipot**. But when my `edittext` is **Malilipot-Santo Domingo, Santo Domingo-Bacacay** it's always calling for the first condition **(Tabaco-Malinao)** not their own condition.

Could be the condition is wrong? or the logical operators that I'm using?

My understanding is that, it takes what comes first and not taking the equal sign correctly. *This could be wrong*.

```
String origin = etOrigin.getText().toString();
    String destination = etDestination.getText().toString();
            if (origin.equals("Tabaco") == destination.equals("Malinao") && origin.equals("Malinao") == destination.equals("Tabaco")) {
            ttom();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tabaco malinao", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (origin.equals("Tabaco") == destination.equals("Bacacay") && origin.equals("Bacacay") == destination.equals("Tabaco")) {
            ttob();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tabaco bacacay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (origin.equals("Tabaco") == destination.equals("Santo Domingo") && origin.equals("Santo Domingo") == destination.equals("Tabaco")) {
            ttosto();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tabaco sto domingo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (origin.equals("Tabaco") == destination.equals("Malilipot") && origin.equals("Malilipot") == destination.equals("Tabaco")) {
            ttomali();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tabaco malilipot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (origin.equals("Malilipot") == destination.equals("Santo Domingo") && origin.equals("Santo Domingo") == destination.equals("Malilipot")) {
            malitosto();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "malilipot sto domingo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (origin.equals("Malilipot") == destination.equals("Bacacay") && origin.equals("Bacacay") == destination.equals("Malilipot")) {
            malitobac();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "malilipot bacacay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (origin.equals("Santo Domingo") == destination.equals("Bacacay") && origin.equals("Bacacay") == destination.equals("Santo Domingo")) {
            bactosto();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sto domingo bacacay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid input!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Why do you connect every stamenet with _&&_? Did you want to use the logical-Or _||_?

Comment: I've tried changing the && to || and not changing the == to something, and that's where I made a mistake. Because I'm thinking that the origin should equals to the destination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is wrong, let's say that you have :

```
String origin = "Malilipot";

String destination = "Santo Domingo";
```

Then `origin.equals("Tabaco")` is `false`
and `destination.equals("Malinao")` is also `false` .

So `origin.equals("Tabaco") == destination.equals("Malinao")` yields `false == false` which is `true`, despite the fact that it absolutely doesn't match what you thought was your condition.

Refactor your code to only use `&&` (AND) and `||` (OR) operators :

```
if (origin.equals("Tabaco") == destination.equals("Malinao") && origin.equals("Malinao") == destination.equals("Tabaco"))
```

Becomes

```
if ((origin.equals("Tabaco") && destination.equals("Malinao")) || (origin.equals("Malinao") && destination.equals("Tabaco")))
```

Comment: I'm a bit correct that the equal sign ("==") is the problem. I've tried to change the && to || but not changing the == to &&. Thank you for the effort correcting my mistake

Answer (score 2):

Change the condition like below ,in your case when you enter **Malilipot-Santo Domingo** as per first condition

`if (origin.equals("Tabaco") == destination.equals("Malinao") && origin.equals("Malinao") == destination.equals("Tabaco"))`

**origin.equals("Tabaco") is false and destination.equals("Malinao") is also false then false == false it become true same for next condition**

```
String origin = etOrigin.getText().toString();
        String destination = etDestination.getText().toString();
                if ((origin.equals("Tabaco") && destination.equals("Malinao")) ||( origin.equals("Malinao") == destination.equals("Tabaco"))) {
                ttom();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tabaco malinao", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if ((origin.equals("Tabaco") && destination.equals("Bacacay")) || ( origin.equals("Bacacay") && destination.equals("Tabaco"))) {
                ttob();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tabaco bacacay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if ((origin.equals("Tabaco") && destination.equals("Santo Domingo")) ||( origin.equals("Santo Domingo") && destination.equals("Tabaco")) ){
                ttosto();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tabaco sto domingo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if ((origin.equals("Tabaco") && destination.equals("Malilipot") )||( origin.equals("Malilipot") && destination.equals("Tabaco"))) {
                ttomali();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tabaco malilipot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if ((origin.equals("Malilipot") && destination.equals("Santo Domingo") )||( origin.equals("Santo Domingo") && destination.equals("Malilipot"))){
                malitosto();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "malilipot sto domingo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if ((origin.equals("Malilipot") && destination.equals("Bacacay")) ||( origin.equals("Bacacay") && destination.equals("Malilipot"))) {
                malitobac();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "malilipot bacacay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (origin.equals("Santo Domingo") && destination.equals("Bacacay") )||( origin.equals("Bacacay") && destination.equals("Santo Domingo"))) {
                bactosto();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sto domingo bacacay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid input!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the explanation why it's going in the first condition...

```
String origin = "Malilipot";
    String destination = "Santo Domingo";
    if(origin.equals("Tabaco") == destination.equals("Malinao") && origin.equals("Malinao") == destination.equals("Tabaco"))

    origin.equals("Tabaco")  = false
    destination.equals("Malinao") = false
    origin.equals("Tabaco") == destination.equals("Malinao")
            false           ==      false 
            result will be  = true

    origin.equals("Malinao")  = false
    destination.equals("Tabaco") = false

    origin.equals("Malinao") == destination.equals("Tabaco")
                    false    ==       false

            result will be = true


    at your last condition will be if (true == true)
            it will be : true


    thats why its going in first condition
```